# Open android app from android default browser

Tags: android, android-intent

I try to open my app from the browser not able to do this till now.
I found many solution on web and try to make my code working. a added this code to my manifest file and try to open my app from browser by typing url on android default browser but it is not asking for any dialog chooser and just open url on browser, Please tell me what i am doing wrong. Help me please. Thanks in advance.

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"></action>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"></category>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"></category>
    <data android:scheme="http" android:host="www.google.com"></data>
 </intent-filter>
```

Answer (score 1):

you cant open any applications by typing on Browser

By clicking any link of http://www.google.com you can open this application

Send an email to that mobile by sending http://www.google.com

and open the link from the email now it will opens your application

Comment: But we can get chooser dialog for the url "market.android.com". and i can also add my app to this chooser dialog by adding <data android:scheme="https" android:host="market.android.com"></data> what is this?